# Eclipse doesn't show me the errors and I can't delete the project without eliminate the files from the disk

Tags: eclipse, maven, delete-file

I have imported into my eclipse, a set of java files as a maven project but now I cant see the usual errors in the code like normal new java projects presents. I can type whatever I want on the file that I dont get an error... why? How can I activate the "compilation on the fly" that Eclipse usually do?

Another doubt I have, is how to delete one project from eclipse without deleting the files from the disk?

Help please

Comment: PS: Regarding the deleting files question, I dont want to use the filter option to hide closed projects. I really want to delete the projects but maintain the files on the disk.

Comment: This is really 2 questions, not a single question.

Comment: Regarding the first question, there's not really enough detail. You should be more precise in describing what you have and what you've done.

Comment: Did you try to remove the project in eclipse, run mvn eclipse:clean and re-import it (as a maven project) again?